# Social Media plugins for WordPress

Tags: feature-request, blog

It would be useful to have WordPress plugins for FaceBook and Google+, so when new blog entries are posted readers could be informed through their chosen social media provider.

These plugins should post a link to both facebook and google+, every time a new blog entry is published (similar to how new entries are tweeted).

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: The first part made me think you meant something that allowed the reader to post to more than twitter. Then it sounds like something different. Can you elaborate? Do you happen to know of a plugin we can use?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff What I'm really looking for, is to have a link to new blog posts posted to both the facebook and google+ pages automatically.  [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) seems to be able to do that with facebook, but I couldn't find one for google+.