# Can we add a way to automatically post blog links to Twitter, Google+ and Facebook?

Tags: feature-request

It sounds like there are some changes to the blog in the works, so while work is being done I thought it might be time to re-request a feature.  In a previous question I asked for [WordPress plug-ins to automatically post links to social media sites](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/33).

Since the blog is getting work done, could this be baked in?

## How it should work

When a new blog entry is published, a link should be automatically posted to Twitter, Facebook, and Google+ (and possibly other social media sites).

I'm not sure if other SE blogs have [google+](https://plus.google.com/107413671752847316156/posts) or [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/pages/DIY-Stack-Exchange-Blog/221805181245656) accounts, but here at Home Improvement we try to get the word out when new entries are published. Unfortunately, this is currently a manual process.

It would be really nice, if all we had to do is set a publish date/time for an entry. Then on that day the article would be published, and a link would be posted to twitter, facebook, and google+.